# Why is Gradle Rich Versioning applied inconsistently?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a kotlin library module which has been published to mavenLocal in versions `1.0.0`, `1.0.1`, `1.1.0`, `1.2.0`, `1.2.1` and `2.0.0`. Let's call it `corp.acme:lib`

I have an android library module which uses `corp.acme:lib` as a dependency and defines the following constraint.

```
dependencies {
    implementation("corp.acme:lib") {
        version {
            strictly("[1.0.1, 2.0.0[")
            prefer("1.2.1")
        }
    }

    constraints {
        implementation("corp.acme:lib") {
            version {
                strictly("[1.0.1, 2.0.0[")
                prefer("1.2.1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that it defines a strict version range between `1.0.1` (inclusive) and `2.0.0` (exclusive), with a preference for `1.2.1`
Let's call the android library module `corp.planetexpress:lib`. It is released in version `0.0.1`, but this is irrelevant.

Now, I have an app that uses `corp.planetexpress:lib:1.0.0`. So far so good. Everything works.

Once I declare a direct dependency to `corp.acme:lib:1.0.0` within the app, then I would expect Gradle's strict versioning to kick in and produce a build error. However, it doesn't, it automatically updates `corp.acme:lib` to the preferred `1.2.1`. I can live with that, but in my opinion it is inconsistent because if I add a direct dependency to `corp.acme:lib` outside of the defined range on the other side, e.g. `corp.acme:lib.2.0.0`, then the build of the app fails as expected explaining the defined version of the direct dependency is outside of the imposed constraint.

Additionally, if I define the direct dependency to `corp.acme:lib` within the app as strict (no matter on which side, i.e `1.0.0!!` or `2.0.0!!`), then Gradle just ignores the constraints of `corp.planetexpress:lib` and just forces 1.0.0 or 2.0.0 within the final build of the app, which is unexpected.

All of the above libraries are published to mavenLocal and consumed via it. I have also observed that the gradle module metadata is generated and lives alongside them in .m2/.
I use version 8.2 of the android gradle plugin.

So here are my questions.

1. Why does the resolution fail the build, only if the defined direct dependency to `corp.acme:lib` in the app is higher than the defined range, but not lower?
2. Why doesn't the strict declaration within the app (`1.0.0!!` or `2.0.0!!`) produce a build error, as it clashes with the strict declaration of `corp.planetexpress:lib`, but just ignores the one of the library?
3. Is there are way to enforce a build error if the host app uses a library version outside of my defined range?